# Using GetKeyState to create 3 key hotkey without triggering another similar 2 key hotkey

Tags: autohotkey

**Problem**

When a 3 key hotkey (`LShift`+`CapsLock`+`LButton`) is pressed, the a similar 2 key hotkey (`CapsLock`+`LButton`) is triggered instead.

**Questions**

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can the correct message box (`shift left click`) be triggered for the `LShift`+`CapsLock`+`LButton` hotkey?

**Code**

```
SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff
CapsLock::
    MsgBox, "capslock"
return
CapsLock & LButton::
    MsgBox, "left click"
return

; 3 key hotkey
; problem here is when LShift+CapsLock+LButton are pressed, the CapsLock+LButton is 
; triggered instead
#If GetKeyState("LShift", "P") && GetKeyState("CapsLock", "P")
    LButton::
        MsgBox, "shift left click"
    return
#If
```

**Example scenario**

- Press `CapsLock`, and correct message box (`capslock`) appears
- Press `CapsLock`+`LButton`, and correct message box (`left click`)  appears
- Press `LShift`+`CapsLock`+`LButton`, and incorrect message box (`left click`)  appears (message box (`shift left click`) should have appeared)
- Press `CapsLock`+`LShift`+`LButton`, and incorrect message box (`left click`)  appears (message box (`shift left click`) should have appeared)

**What I've tried**

- Checking the [`#If`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm) directive documentation, it mentions a timeout that could affect the button combination, however, pressing the buttons at varying speeds still causes the `CapsLock`+`LButton` hotkey to trigger
- Using nested regular `if`, `else if`, & `else` statements
  instead of the `#If` directive to alter the order of the 3 key
  hotkey
- Using `$` modifer to prevent the 3 key hotkey triggering the `CapsLock`+`LButton` hotkey
- Breaking the 3 key hotkey into parts, e.g., putting a 2 key hotkey within a `#If` `GetKeyState`, i.e.:

  ```
  #If GetKeyState("LShift", "P")
      CapsLock & LButton::
          MsgBox, "shift left click"
      return
  #If
  ```

  This usually gives the correct message (`shift left click`) box but sometimes triggers the CapsLock hotkey giving the incorrect message box (`capslock`)

Comment: What about `if (GetKeyState("LShift", "P"))` in the `CapsLock & LButton` hotkey?

Comment: @JoshBrobst I tried ([pastebin](https://pastebin.com/RGaj8H0h)) ```if (GetKeyState("LShift", "P"))``` in ```CapsLock & LButton``` with ```#If``` and regular ```if```/```else``` both stop ```CapsLock & LButton``` & the 3 key hotkey firing their ```MsgBox```

Comment: Oh I mean using the true part of that if-statement to implement the 3-key hotkey, [like this](https://pastebin.com/MGL149J9)

Comment: @JoshBrobst Excellent idea, that works & is more stable than my previous solutions (when ```LShift``` is the last key released after the hotkey is triggered, e.g., ```LShift``` down+```CapsLock``` down then ```CapsLock``` up+```LShift``` up correctly doesn't trigger ```CapsLock``` hotkey but ```CapsLock``` hotkey is triggered if CapsLock is the last key released after the hotkey is triggered)

Comment: @JoshBrobst Can you put your solution as an answer to this question so it can be accepted so others with a similar problem can find it faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having a separate 3-key hotkey, you can test for shift inside the 2-key hotkey to implement both `CapsLock + LButton` and `CapsLock + Shift + LButton`:

```
SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff

CapsLock::
    MsgBox, "capslock"
return

CapsLock & LButton::
    if (GetKeyState("LShift", "P")) {
        MsgBox, "shift left click"
    }
    else {
        MsgBox, "left click"
    }
return
```

Avoiding code duplication for similar hotkeys:

- Using a [function](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm)

  ```
  CapsLock & RButton::CapsMouseHandler("right")
  CapsLock & LButton::CapsMouseHandler("left")

  CapsMouseHandler(btnString) {
      if (GetKeyState("LShift", "P")) {
          MsgBox % "shift " btnString " click"
      }
      else {
          MsgBox % btnString " click"
      }
  }
  ```
- Using [A_ThisHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#ThisHotkey)

  ```
  CapsLock & RButton::
  CapsLock & LButton::
      btnString := InStr(A_ThisHotkey, "LButton") ? "left" : "right"
      if (GetKeyState("LShift", "P")) {
          MsgBox % "shift " btnString " click"
      }
      else {
          MsgBox % btnString " click"
      }
  return
  ```

Comment: Thanks, this works. If I have many 2 key hotkeys (e.g., ```CapsLock```+```LButton```, ```CapsLock```+```RButton```, etc.), this results in code repetition ([pastebin](https://pastebin.com/W3zVSEAF)). Is there a way to refactor your solution to avoid code repetition?

Comment: Yes, since hotkeys are actually [labels](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Labels.htm) you can simply put `CapsLock & RButton::` on the line right above `CapsLock & LButton::` and they will both run the same code.

Comment: Then you can test against [`A_ThisHotkey`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#ThisHotkey) to branch based upon the left or right button to change the message. Or, you could separate the hotkeys and move it into a function. I'll add an example to the answer.

Comment: Brilliant ideas, the function & A_ThisHotkey methods both work (function method seems more concise and readable), +1 for reducing code repetition, really appreciate the help :)

Comment: Happy to help! I definitely agree that using functions is much clearer. I try to use functions rather than subroutines/commands wherever possible.